# Creating a 3D Surface Plot from a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have been searching for this quite a while, but cannot find an answer to my problem or a minimum example. I would like to make a 3D-plot of a matrix.

An extract of my data looks like this. There are the years, which I would like to use as X-Axis. There is Y, which I would like to use as Y and I would like to plot z.

```
Year       y     z
2000       1     467
2000       2   10678
2000       2      25
...
```

How can I make this a surface plot?

Best

Comment: That format for data is not a "matrix" at least in R-terminology, although it is in the long-form needed by some of the plotting paradigms. The three plotting paradigms I think of are: 1) base-graphics (functions `persp` and `contour` and the 'plot3D'-package mentioned below), 2) lattice (functions `wireframe` and `contourplot`) and  3) RGL( function `surface3d`). There are many worked examples on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for how to plot a surface plot in R? It turns out there's at least a `persp` function, a package called [`plot3D`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf), [`wireframe`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-surface-plots/) in lattice and [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/).

For starters, try (from the plot3D package vignette)

```
library(plot3D)
example(persp3D)
example(surf3D)
example(slice3D)
example(scatter3D)
example(segments3D)
example(image2D)
example(image3D)
example(contour3D)
example(colkey)
example(jet.col)
example(perspbox)
example(mesh)
example(trans3D)
example(plot.plist)
example(ImageOcean)
example(Oxsat)
```

Comment: @BondedDust luckily the link had is spelled out right. :)